# How to repair blind bracket screw coming out of top surface of window frame

Tags: drywall, mounting, studs, blinds, window-frame

I moved into a house with some pretty nice blinds installed already, Hunter Douglas Duette (I think). The blind I'm looking at has 4 plastic brackets ([these ones specifically](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00KEHAZL8)) which are screwed directly into the top surface (horizontal, down-facing) of the window frame, using #6 x 1-1/2" screws (as shown on page 2 of the manual [here](http://cdn.hunterdouglas.com/static/product/DU-AP_Cordlock_IOC_5109604168_0414_1.pdf)). The screw on the right-most bracket is no longer securely threaded at all, it has stripped out whatever it is screwed into and is providing no support. I don't know enough about construction to know if it was screwed into a stud or not (I can find a stud in a wall, but this area is trickier). I know windows are framed in wood, but I'm guessing this particular screw wasn't hitting wood, because when screwed in all the way and pulled on (soft enough not to slip a thread), you can watch the entire painted surface flex like a balloon, which makes me think I'm pulling on plaster or something soft. Wood threads is hard to strip, and wood would not flex.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAAjK.jpg) is an image of the entire blind (sorry for poor quality). You can see the right edge sagging as I have removed the bracket. The textured/painted surface available for screwing into is 3" deep. The holes for the 4 brackets are just under 3/4" back from the front edge (see the exposed hole below).

[image]

One more look at the top surface from below (behind the blind), though this doesn't really offer much information.

[image]

Since I suspect the screw was not reaching wood, I'm not sure what to do.

- Reuse the same hole, with a longer screw? This would only help if there is some wood that was beyond the reach of the 1.5" screw, but I don't know.
- Reuse the same hole, with a #8 screw? I suspect this would be a temporary fix only and would eventually start pulling out like the #6 did.
- Move the bracket to the left a little bit and make a new hole? At least I'm not reusing the same bad hole, but this doesn't really solve the main issue, and it also makes things worse since I'm moving the bracket further from the pull string (the stress from which is what caused this bracket screw to fail before the other 3, I imagine).
- Use some sort of drywall insert? Again, I don't actually know what's under the texture/paint here. I'm guessing it's more substantial than just drywall, since the other 3 screws are holding. What else could be there? Sheet metal of some sort? I have no clue.
- Move the brackets back further? Maybe that is a way to find the window frame, but now the blind won't be aligned with the wall anymore, but rather recessed.

Open to ideas! I will probably start by trying the longer screw in the same hole, since I don't think that could make anything worse.

Comment: If you take down the blind you can probe the hole to figure out what you're screwing into.  You could try a long screw to see if it bites something but there is some risk of hitting an electrical wire.  Depending what the material is, it might be preferable to use the right kind of insert.  Is it plaster?  The finish is extremely uneven for gypsum board.

Comment: Also from your pictures it's not clear if the screws go through the back of the blind body or if they attach separate brackets that may be adjustable.

Comment: Is this a brick wall? If so you might have trouble installing the bracket, as there could be a metal lintel above, then you would need to drill through the metal into the brick, then fasten the brackets using longer screws. If this is the case, you might be better off just purchasing a new blind with side supports.

Comment: If there is a metal lintel, you may drill through and thread it to receive a machine screw.

Comment: I ended up using a longer screw and drilling a new pilot hole that angles slightly back away from the room. I am fairly certain this allowed the screw to bite into the window frame, which the previous screw was just barely grabbing the surface of, at the boundary between it and the drywall.